# Why does TensorFlow have a lot of mathematical equations re-implemented?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I was looking through the API in [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) and notice that a lot of mathematical operations that already exist in python and **numpy** have been re-implemented (or at least given a tensorflow interface). For example:

[image]

is there a good reason to do this?

I've been searching over their page but can't find why they'd do this.

I do have some guesses though. One of my main guesses is that they probably want those operations to have some backpropagation effect on whatever Neural network graph that gets implementat. In other words, have their derivatives implemented. Is this one of the reasons? (wish I knew how to even check if my guess is right)

For example, in one of the most basic examples of linear regression, one defines the prediction function that one wants to implement:

```
product = tf.matmul(x,W)
y = product + b
```

instead of

```
product = tf.matmul(x,W)
y = tf.add(product, b)
```

Somehow the first implementation does not interfere with Stochastic Gradient Descent algorithm for training, so it probably doesn't matter if one uses numpy or tf.add to train? This is one aspect that confuses me, when do I know which one should I be using.

Or maybe they are performance reasons? Or maybe its to give those operations access to GPU if required to use GPUs?

Comment: To be able to have same TF program run on GPU, TPU, Android, iOS and future hardware

Comment: Btw a+b uses tf.add in your example, not numpy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to understand that you create a tensorflow graph with this operation, meaning they aren't the same as the numpy functions, they are more an abstraction of them.

Maybe you have noticed that you have to create a session and then evaluate the functions through that session to get a result, where with numpy functions they are executed directly. this is because this graph and its functions define what to do like writing down a formula, but to get results for a specific x (or whatever) you have to insert a value for x. This is what your doing through session and eval.

So to conclude this you define a graph with tensorflow which is a more abstract representation of the functions and the graph also isn't executed at runtime, then it is defined, it will be executed when you call the eval function and through that run the session.

Also notice that you cant mix numpy functions and tensorflow functions directly but you can define own tensorflow functions (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html)

Btw I guess most of the tensorflow functions are using numpy under the hood. :)

Comment: Ok, that is what I suspected. However, tensorflow seems to be ok with mixing the two. Do you mind clarifying that? For example, `y = tf.matmul(x,W) + b`. The  `+` isn't a tensor flow operation but it still works fine when building the graph (I assume). Do you mind clarifying this mix of ops between tf ops and np ops?

Comment: The + operator is overloaded meaning that + is the same as tf.add this works because x, W and b are not numbers or numpy objects they are tensors. If you want to learn more about operator overloading simply google for it, its kind of fun :)

Comment: that makes sense! :) I do know about op overload so I know what you mean. Sort of rusty in python but that explains a lot. How can I check what operations are officially overloaded? For example, if I want to do `1/x` I'd like it to actually do `tf.div(1,x)`. But writing tf.op makes the code much less readable so I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: I don't know a special resource where you can finde all the overloaded operators but I guess most of them are and otherwise you should get an error cause a mentioned you can't mix default functions/operations with tensorflow op's so simply try using them and you should be fine!

Comment: Last (important) question, about the derivatives, I assume that means that the derivatives for these overloaded operations have already been computed for us so the SGD works fine?

Comment: Yes tensorflow does all the dirty work for us meaning you do not have to derivate anything. :D